# Getting value value from textbox inside loop with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a table in my project, I loop the trs in this table. There are textboxes in the table. When I make changes and want to save, it takes action based on the first record. I share the image

[image]

The second record in the picture above "toptan" I changed it to. but the record that came to me "Perakendee"
So my code always gets the value of the first record. Is there a way to solve this? Or a more Logical coding

HTML codes

```
<table id="kullanicilistesi" class="table mb-3 table-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Şirket Adı</th>
      <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Database (Veri Tabanı)</th>
      <th class="border-bottom text-center py-3">Şube</th>
      <th class="border-bottom text-center py-3">Diğer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in AdminStatic.GetIsletme()) {
    <tr>
      <td class="">
        <input type="text" id="isletmeadi" class="form-control" value="@item.IsletmeAdi" />
      </td>
      <td class=""> <input type="text" id="veritabani" class="form-control" value="@item.VeriTabani" /></td>
      <td class=""> <input type="text" id="sube" class="form-control" value="@item.Sube" /></td>
      <td class="">
        <a style="color:limegreen;" href`your text`="javascript:void(0)" data-idd="@item.ID" onclick="IsletmeDuzenle(this)">
          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>
        </a>
        <a style="color: rgb(217, 37, 37); " href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="IsletmeSil(@item.ID)">
          <i class="uil uil-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript Codes

```
function IsletmeDuzenle(t) {
    var id = $(t).data('idd');
    alert($("#isletmeadi").val());
    getValue($baseUrl + "/B2BAdmin/IsletmeDuzenle",
        { id: id, isletmeAdi: $("#isletmeadi").val(), veritabani: $("#veritabani").val(), sube: $("#sube").val() },
        function (data, err) {
            if (data=="Basarili") {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Başarılı',
                    html: 'İşletme Başarıyla Güncellenmiştir',
                    icon: 'success'
                }).then(function (result) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Remove ALL those static ID's as they produce duplicate ID in the DOM which is invalid HTML `id="isletmeadi"`

Comment: So how do I go about removing it?

Comment: Use an editor and delete them? OR replace with something specific for each item which might have an id or some such?  This appears to be MVC so probably mark it with that tag?

Comment: `id="(@item.ID)isletmeadi" ` Do I use as

Comment: Only you know what your actual unique id might be given our limited peek into this.  Also you appear to have jQuery in this based on `$("#isletmeadi").val()` - however it is not clear what the intent is of that JavaScript at this point and likely that needs to change also.

Comment: Yes, I also changed the Javascript side as follows: `$("#" + id + "isletmeadi").val() ` **This worked :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to illustrate you can do this without id's and have multiple I did a fake mock-up and some ugly colors with some event handlers NOT embedded in the HTML.
I also removed empty `class=""` just to have a cleaner visual of the HTML.

```js
function goGetThem(them) {
  console.log("Called:", them);
  return; // just to not do the call

  getValue(them.getUrl, them.callParameters,
    function(data, err) {
      if (data == "Basarili") {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Başarılı',
          html: 'İşletme Başarıyla Güncellenmiştir',
          icon: 'success'
        }).then(function(result) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      }
    });
}
$('.green-container')
  .on('click', '.go-green-button', function(event) {
    console.log('check clicked');
    const $editRow = $(this).closest('.business-container');
    const $tableContainer = $(event.delegateTarget);
    console.log($editRow.find('.database-name').val());
    const baseurl = $tableContainer.data("baseurl");
    const them = {
      getUrl: baseurl + "/B2BAdmin/IsletmeDuzenle",
      callParameters: {
        id: $(this).data('idd'),
        isletmeAdi: $editRow.find(".isletmeadi").val(),
        veritabani: $editRow.find(".veritabani").val(),
        sube: $editRow.find(".sube").val()
      }
    };
    goGetThem(them);
  }).on('click', ".remove-button", function(event) {
    let mytd = $(this).closest('td');
    mytd.toggleClass("delete-me");
    // for fun we just toggle the data and make it "pretty" on clicks
    $(this).closest('.business-container').get(0).dataset.todelete = mytd.hasClass('delete-me') ? "yes" : "no";
    //console.log('Go remove:', this.innerHTML);
  });
```

```css
.remove-button.btn {
  color: #D92525;
}

.go-green.button {
  color: #32CD32;
}

.delete-me {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.business-container:not([data-todelete]) {
  background-color: #22222204;
}

.business-container[data-todelete="yes"] {
  background-color: #FF000008;
}

.business-container[data-todelete="no"] {
  background-color: #00FF0008;
}

.link-container .uil {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.2.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table mb-3 table-center green-container" data-baseurl="/fun/urlforgreen/">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Şirket Adı</th>
      <th class="border-bottom text-start py-3">Database (Veri Tabanı)</th>
      <th class="border-bottom text-center py-3">Şube</th>
      <th class="border-bottom text-center py-3">Diğer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="container">
    <tr class="container container-row business-container">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control business-name isletmeadi" value="Happy business" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control database-name veritabani" value="Fun Database" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control sube" value="Branch5" /></td>
      <td class="link-container">
        <a class="go-green-button btn" href="#" data-idd="branch-5">
          <i class="uil bi-check"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="remove-button btn" href="#" data-idd="branch-5">
          <i class="uil bi-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="container container-row business-container">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control business-name isletmeadi" value="Car business" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control database-name veritabani" value="Car Database" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control sube" value="branch454" /></td>
      <td class="link-container">
        <a class="go-green-button btn" href="#" data-idd="row-454">
          <i class="uil bi-check"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="remove-button btn" href="#" data-idd="row-454">
          <i class="uil bi-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good with turkish but it looks like trying to update or delete rows.
On checkmark: onclick="IsletmeDuzenle(this)" 
On trashcan: onclick="IsletmeSil(@item.ID)"

I'm guessing its the checkmark that is not behaving as you want it to. If it's for an update, you could pass the ID like with the trashcan.
If all the rows are imported and only need to change and/or get deleted, I think a function that does that that takes the ID of the entry is the best way. But then you need to have the ID in that object, even if you don't show it.

So,
On checkmark: onclick="somefunction(@item.ID)"

Comment: You are right but first the update part `IsletmeDüzenle(@item.ID)` It was like that, then I changed it. It works both ways, no problem right now

Comment: Okay, thats great to hear. Good luck!